# Exclude current post from an array of posts?

Tags: wp-query, exclude

I'm trying to exclude the current post from an array and I know that the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) says that it's not possible to combine **post__in** and **post__not_in** in the same query...

But in wordpress everything (well, almost...) is possible and I know that must be a way to exclude the current post from my posts array.

If I can't use the together, how can I exclude current post from the array? Any hints are very welcome.

This is my current query:

```
$this_post = $post->ID;
$args = array('post__in' => array(17,111,108,158), 'post__not_in' => array($this_post));
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to remove the current post ID from an array of other post IDs.

```
$include = array( 17, 111, 108, 158);
$include = array_diff( $include, array( $post->ID ) );
$args = array( 'post__in' => $include );
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Edit to include a point raised by [Pieter Goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230321/exclude-current-post-from-an-array-of-posts/230322?noredirect=1#comment341964_230322)--If `$include` is not a hard-coded array of IDs but something that comes from the database, you should verify that it is not `empty()` prior to performing the query. Passing an empty array to `'post__in'` will get an unfiltered list of posts, rather than returning no posts as you might expect.

Comment: Just a tip here, before passing any variable like `$include` to `post__in`, always make sure that you are not passing an empty array. Passing an empty array to `post__in` will return all posts regardless, it will not return an empty array as one would think

Comment: @PieterGoosen so, is this code correct, Or should I do something else? Sorry to ask, but i'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "make sure that you are not passing an empty array". `$include` is not empty... or is it?

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to clarify that point.